# How to destring nonnumeric variables in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am not able to  destring nonnumeric variables in Stata

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Xp2.png)

Here is the error message

Answer (score 1):

What usually works for me is:

```
destring variable, dpcomma replace
```

For a better solution I would need a view on your data.

Also, if the "nonnumeric" means categorical, you would have to:

```
encode variable, gen(encoded_variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out which characters are problematic with something like

```
tab q31 if missing(real(q31))
```

as this will show the characters other than comma that are problematic.