# Why am I not able to do foreach loop and carryforward together?

Tags: stata

When this code "bysort countrycode:carryforward 'var', gen(new 'var')" is included in a foreach var loop, Stata gives me an error message. How to solve this?

Comment: You got two answers to your previous question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75537937/how-to-destring-nonnumeric-variables-in-stata -- so please reply to those, indicating what worked, and/or what didn't.

Answer (score 1):

There are two evident errors in the code you cite. The punctuation for referencing a local macro should be different. A new variable name may not include a space.

```
bysort countrycode:carryforward 'var', gen(new 'var')
```

should be

```
bysort countrycode:carryforward `var', gen(new`var')
```

If this isn't the answer, we need to see the exact code you used and the error message that you got. Indeed, the question falls short of a minimal reproducible example as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example